# AUTOSYS JOB creation

Tags: jobs, autosys

i have jOB A and JOB B , job A is schedule at 11:00AM (on sunday and monday)and job B is sheduled at 4:PM on national and bank holidays (which includes all the days ie sunday and monday).

i want job B to run only if A has not run EX : if there is national holiday on sunday and if job has run on sunday 11 AM then Job B shud not run on that that .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, job B is running on a user defined Holiday Calendar called "nation-bank-holidays"

Update the following in the Job A job definition:

```
exclude_calendar: nation-bank-holidays
```

Job A would be scheduled as per the regular defined calendar /days but will not be scheduled to on the days defined in nation-bank-holidays calendar. On those days, only job B would be scheduled at 4pm.